# I want to get following output by using procedure or query anything in sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have 2 tables and i want result which i have mention below.
i am using sql server 2012
tables are:

emp

```
╔═══════╦═════════╦═════╦════════╗
║ empid ║  ename  ║ sal ║ deptno ║
╠═══════╬═════════╬═════╬════════╣
║     1 ║ vikrant ║   5 ║      1 ║
║     2 ║ Nimesh  ║   2 ║      1 ║
║     3 ║ memo    ║   6 ║      2 ║
║     4 ║ sabir   ║   5 ║      2 ║
╚═══════╩═════════╩═════╩════════╝
```

dept

```
╔════════╦══════════════╗
║ deptno ║    dname     ║
╠════════╬══════════════╣
║      1 ║ Tech         ║
║      2 ║ Creative     ║
╚════════╩══════════════╝
```

Result/output:Total 6 Row

```
╔══════════╦═══╗
║ Tech     ║   ║
║ Vikrant  ║ 5 ║
║ Nimesh   ║ 2 ║
║ Creative ║   ║
║ Memo     ║ 6 ║
║ Sabir    ║ 5 ║
╚══════════╩═══╝
```

I want in 1st row Tech that is dept name then in 2nd row emp name in that dpt and his salary that is his/her dpt name should be printed once and then emp name sal of all emp in that dpt, abv is just an example

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Show your try.

Comment: Quite unsusual format, do you need this for an arbitrary number of departments or is this number rather fixed and small?

Comment: A result set must have the same number of columns in each row, as well as the same column names and data types.  What do you expect for the employee id of the department rows?

Comment: nope, I want in 1st row Tech that is dept name then in 2nd row emp name in that dpt and his salary that is his/her dpt name should be printed once and then emp name sal of all emp in that dpt, abv is just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a header for every department?

This should work:

```
SELECT ColumnName = ColumnName + ISNULL(' ' + x.Sal, '')
FROM(
    SELECT ColumnName = d.dname, 
           deptno, IsDepartment = 1,
           emp_Id = -1, 
           sal = ''
    FROM dbo.Dept d

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ColumnName = e.ename, 
           deptno,  IsDepartment = 0,
           emp_Id = id, 
           CAST(sal as varchar(10))
    FROM dbo.Emp e
) x
ORDER BY x.deptno, x.IsDepartment DESC, x.Sal DESC
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6be13/16/0)</kbd>

**Edit**: you have changed your sample data but not your requirement, have you?

Comment: suppose table have 3 column 1st column should get tech in 1st row,then second row 2nd and 3rd column should get emp name and sal.not like what u gave

Comment: @user3816325: what means "nope,suppose the table having 3 column"? Which table has three columns, why does your desired result contain only one column if you actually want three?

Comment: @user3816325: a resultset always has the same number of columns. You cannot select a row with one column and another with three. That's why i've combined them with `ColumnName + ISNULL(' ' + x.Sal, '')`. Of course you could select three columns and leave two empty for the department-rows. But i'm sure that you've got the idea now. It should be simple to modify above to get your desired result.

Comment: it doesn't matter if 1st row have 3 column then too

Comment: What three columns do you want at all? You've only shown the name and sal column in your desired result.

Comment: table with 3 columns and many rows as per entry i:e number of emp in that dept.now 1st row 1st column(1*1) should get tech as a dpt and nxt 2 col in 1st row should be blank,then in 2nd row 1st col should be blank and 2nd and 3rd should get emp name and sal n so on i hope u understood now

Comment: @user3816325: so why don't you explain and show your requirement in the first place? Edit your question with the real requirement(text, sample data and desired result). Use the `code`-button in the editor to format it properly (explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)).

Comment: so finally can u give me a solution?

Comment: its urgent and u can use cursor inside procedure

Comment: Just because you can use a cursor does NOT mean it is a good idea. You can also use a hammer to drive screws in a nice piece of furniture but I wouldn't recommend that either.

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please help yourself by posting a link to SQL Fiddle.

Here's another query you can use. GROUPING SETS are pretty much like UNION ALL, but more concise.

```
SELECT      dname,
            ename,
            CASE
                WHEN ename IS NULL THEN dname
                ELSE ename
            END             As [Dept/Employee],
            CASE
                WHEN ename IS NULL THEN ''
                ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10),SUM(sal))
            END             As [Salary]
FROM        emp
INNER JOIN  dept    ON emp.deptno = dept.deptno
GROUP BY    GROUPING SETS (dname, (dname, ename))
ORDER BY    dname, ename
```

For clarity, I added the `dname` and `ename` columns to result set. Remove them in your code. The `CONVERT(varchar(10),...)` is needed because the `Salary` column must have a single data type. If you choose `int/float`, the department-level line will show up as 0. So I converted it to `varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with two separate queries, one returning employees and their salaries:

```
SELECT
  ename,
  sal
FROM
  emp
;
```

and the other, departments:

```
SELECT
  dname
FROM
  dept
;
```

Now you just need to combine the two result sets to make a single output. You can use UNION ALL for that:

```
SELECT
  ename AS name,
  sal
FROM
  emp

UNION ALL

SELECT
  dname,
  NULL
FROM
  dept
;
```

You can see that the second subquery returns a second column, filling it with NULLs. The second column is necessary because queries combined with UNION or UNION ALL must have the same number of columns (and types of corresponding columns across all SELECTs must be compatible; NULL is compatible with any type).

You can also see that the `ename` column is renamed as `name`. This is because the column aliases in the first subquery are used for the entire result set, i.e. columns returned by the second SELECT will assume the names assigned by the first SELECT. So, since the first column is supposed to contain different kinds of names, it would seem to make more sense to specify a neutral alias for it, hence `enames AS names`. You are free to choose a different alias if you like.

Note that the rows in the output will likely be in the wrong order. To make sure that every department name sticks with the corresponding employee names, you can sort the resulting set by `deptno`. To force the department name to go before the employee names in every group, you can further sort the result by `empid`. Now, when you sort a UNION (ALL) query, you must use only columns that are returned by the query. Therefore, `deptno` and `empid` must be added:

```
SELECT
  ename AS name,
  sal,
  deptno,
  empid
FROM
  emp

UNION ALL

SELECT
  dname,
  NULL,
  deptno,
  NULL
FROM
  dept

ORDER BY
  deptno,
  empid
;
```

Rows from `emp` have both `deptno` and `empid`. Rows from `dept` have only `deptno` and will return NULL for `empid`. In SQL Server, a NULL sorts before any other value, so  You can see another NULL in the second SELECT, which corresponds to `empid` returned

This will give you almost what you have asked, except there will be two more columns, `deptno` and `empid`, in the result set. If you really want just the two columns that you showed in your example output, you can use the result of the previous query as a derived table:

```
SELECT
  name,
  sal
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ename AS name,
    sal,
    deptno,
    empid
  FROM
    emp

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    dname,
    NULL,
    deptno,
    NULL
  FROM
    dept
) AS s

ORDER BY
  deptno,
  empid
;
```

This way you can choose some columns just for output (`name` and `sal`) and others just for sorting (`deptno` and `empid`).