# Convert query select to a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I need to convert my SQL Server query in a cursor.

I tried with the example of question [Select statement in cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202398/select-statement-in-cursor) but I had error.

Here my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    U.IDSocio, U.IDUtente,
    U.Cognome, U.Nome, U.Sesso,
    U.Luogo_Nascita,
    U.Provincia_Nascita,
    U.Stato_Nascita,
    COALESCE(C.codice, SS.codice) as Nascita_CodCatastale,
    CONVERT(DATE, U.Data_Nascita) AS Data_Nascita_Orig,
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, U.Data_Nascita, 111), '/', '-') as Data_Nascita,
    U.Indirizzo_Via as Residenza_Indirizzo,
    U.Indirizzo_NumeroCivico as Residenza_NumeroCivico,
    U.Indirizzo_Cap as Residenza_Cap,
    U.Indirizzo_Citta as Residenza_Citta,
    U.Indirizzo_Pv as Residenza_Provincia,
    U.CodCatastaleResidenza as Residenza_CodCatastale,
    U.Indirizzo_Stato as Residenza_Stato,
    U.PIVA,
    U.CodiceFiscale,
    U.Documento,
    U.Telefono_1,
    U.Telefono_2,
    U.SMS,
    U.Email,
    U.Note,
    UG.Descrizione as Categoria,
    U.AutorizzaSMS,
    U.AutorizzaEmail,
    U.AutorizzaCartaceo,
    U.CFRicevuta,
    U.CFRicevutaUtente
FROM [dbo].[Utenti] U
LEFT JOIN dbo.UtenteCustom UC on UC.IDUtente = U.IDUtente
LEFT JOIN dbo.UtentiCategorie UG on UG.IDCategoria = UC.IDCategoriaUtente
LEFT JOIN dbo.Comuni C on C.Comune = U.Luogo_Nascita and C.PV = U.Provincia_Nascita
LEFT JOIN dbo.Comuni SS on SS.Comune = U.Stato_Nascita
INNER JOIN dbo.AbbonamentiIscrizione AI ON U.IDUtente = AI.IDUtente
INNER JOIN dbo.AbbonamentiDurata AD ON AI.IDDurata = AD.IDDurata
INNER JOIN dbo.Abbonamenti A ON A.IDAbbonamento = AD.IDAbbonamento
INNER JOIN dbo.AziendeAbbonamenti AA On AA.IDAbbonamentoCategoria = A.IDCategoria
INNER JOIN dbo.TesseramentiAbbonamentiDurata TAD On TAD.IDDurata = AD.IDDurata
WHERE
    COALESCE(AA.IDRicevutaAzienda, 2) = 2
    AND (U.Cognome <> '' AND U.Nome <> '')
    AND CONVERT(DATE, DataInizio) <= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
    AND CONVERT(DATE, DataFine) >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
    ORDER BY U.IDUtente
```

Could you please help me to convert it into a cursor? I need to use a cursor because the query has many rows as result and the code that use it is too slow to execute.

Comment: Why do you want to convert the query to a cursor? Cursors are iterative processes, which is something that SQL Server performs very poorly at. RDBMS' are designed and perform well with set based operations not RBAR ones. If you have a set based process, and it can stay it as a set based process, then it's almost always best to leave it as one. This has the smell of an [XY Problem](http://http://xyproblem.info/) in truth; what is the problem you are *actually* trying to solve here?

Comment: What error did you receive when you tried making this into a cursor. And, as a reasonable question, why do you need this to be a cursor?  The simple answer to making this a cursor is to add the line `DECLARE Cursor_name CURSOR FOR` right before your SELECT statement.

Comment: You have some low hanging fruit for performance improvement in you where predicates. Three of the four predicates are using a function which renders them nonSARGable and any indexing is useless. But perhaps the two date columns are datetime and you converting them to date, this is one of those rare times a function like that is SARGable. That coalesce however is not. And yeah, converting this to a cursor sounds like a bad idea, especially since you are already saying you have performance issues.

Comment: Also, if you did get an error it makes things infinitely easier for the volunteers you're asking help from if you provide both the SQL you ran to get the error, and the error itself. Without either it is impossible for us to even begin to help you (*however, I still doubt that a `CURSOR` is likely to be the right solution here`).

Comment: @iamdave Sean covers that in his comment. However, he is right, `COALESCE(AA.IDRicevutaAzienda, 2) = 2` should really be `(AA.IDRicevutaAzienda = 2 OR AA.IDRicevutaAzienda IS NULL)`.

Comment: As I said, IF that is a datetime being converted to date it is actually sargable. But if it is a varchar being converted to date then no it certainly isn't. [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea) is a great discussion on the topic.

Comment: @SeanLange  Apologies, seemed to space out on the rest of your comment there.  Long day!

Comment: Converting this to cursor-based logic will almost certainly make it perform worse.

Comment: @iamdave no worries. I do it all the time myself. :)

Comment: Seems the OP hasn't got an answer for "why?"

Comment: Thanks to everyone! I thought to convert to a cursor because the query result has many records and when I execute it, and an other software try, in the meantime, to access or use a transaction on those tables, the other software stop to works. 
So, do you think that is not a good idea convert it to a cursor?

Comment: @Larnu I explained why I would to convert in a cursor.

Comment: So the problem is locking? That is a **completely** different question. A `CURSOR` is only going to make things worse, not better; if it's locking you want to avoid. @SeanLange and I have both commented on why this query isn't SARGable; i suggest that you fix that issue first, and see if the performance is better. if it isn't, provide the **full** DDL for your tables (and indexes) along with the execution plan for your query (via [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)).